# How to access inner elements of an custom element defined through Polymer

Tags: dart, polymer

I'm creating a custom element in Polymer using Dart.  I want to pick up some content from the inside of the tag, like this:

```
<my-element>
  <name>doof</name>
</my-element>
```

Inside the dart code used to handle my-element elements, I find it hard to pick up the content of the "name" element.  The code below illustrates some of the attempts I've made:

```
@CustomTag('my-element')
    class MyElement extends PolymerElement {

     MyElement.created() : super.created() {

           // Will always find the first element in the document. That quickly
           // gets confusing when I have multiple instances of  <my-element> in the
           // document.
           final Element nameElement = querySelector("name");

           // Returns null
           final Element nameElement = shadowRoot.querySelector("name");
     }
}
```

... So I'm confused :-)   Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, leave the `created` constructor alone besides maybe some local variable initialization.
Override lifecycle callbacks like `attached` or `ready` instead.  `querySelector("name");` should work then. If you get the first element in the document then you should use `this.querySelector("name");` (depends on your imports) `shadowRoot.querySelector("name");` is for elements inside the `<template>` tag of your `<my-element>` not for its children (like in your question).

```dart
@CustomTag('my-element')
    class MyElement extends PolymerElement {

     MyElement.created() : super.created();

     @override
     void ready() {

           // Will always find the first element in the document. That quickly
           // gets confusing when I have multiple instances of  <my-element> in the
           // document.
           final Element nameElement = this.querySelector("name");
     }
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem.  Surprisingly, it was necessary to use "this.querySelector". Just using "querySelector" inside the "ready" method was not sufficient.

Comment: This is probably because you import `dart:html` without `as xxx` or `show xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

this.shadowRoot.querySelector() will scan the dom inside the current 'my-element' tag.

with

```
<my-element>
  <div id="myName">doof</div>
<my-element>
```

this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#myName") will return the DivElement

Comment: $['myName'] might be easier here in case it is not inserted dynamically. And it will probably not work because it is not in the `<template>`.